# laravel api package does not recognize my previous routes

Tags: php, laravel

i have a project that already has some api working and now  i wanna use dingo on it  to version my apis  now i just did all the documentation said and yet i get this error in below :

```
{
message: "The version given was unknown or has no registered routes.",
status_code: 400,
```

here is a part of my api.php route

```
$api->version('v1', function (Router $api) {
    $api->group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function(Router $api) {
        $api->group(['middleware' => 'bindings'], function(Router $api) {
            /*************************************************
             *
             * Accommodation Api Crud
             *
             **************************************************/
            $api->get('accommodationbooking', 'App\\Api\\V1\\Controllers\\AccommodationBookingController@index');
```

Any one With similar problem ???

Comment: is this any youse, use Dingo\Api\Exception\UnknownVersionException; link: https://github.com/mmghv/lumen-route-binding/issues/6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you make new routes for you app you have to cache them again the problem was i didnt know that caching routes and api routes are different so i ran :

```
php artisan api:cache
```

because it clears cache first and cache again after that it will recognize your routes